# Where can I find LED indoor floodlights?

Tags: led, recessed-lighting, halogen, bulb

Where can I find LED Indoor Floodlights? I have recessed lighting and one of the lights over a nook in my house gets the person hot who sits under the light for too long - plus LED is more energy efficient. I currently have a halogen indoor flood light installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the major lighting manufacturers are starting to produce LED spots and floods for can lighting - the only downside is they're not cheap.  I've been seeing them at various home improvement centers for 60-100 dollars a bulb depending on the type and wattage.

[Sylvania LED flood @ Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=100670740&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&ci_sku=100670740&ci_src=14110944&cm_mmc=shopping-_-googlebase-_-D27X-_-100670740&locStoreNum=4711&marketID=44)

Answer (score 1):

There are LED or other low wattage versions of a lot of light fitting available.

What you need to do is take out the current bulb to check its size, type and rating and then either go down to your local hardware store or search online for the LED/energy saving equivalent.

However, as @Joe points out, you need to be careful as LEDs radiate the heat differently to normal bulbs so you need to make sure you get one that's rated for use in this manner.

Comment: I know but where.. that is the question!

Comment: @0A0D - where are you based? In the UK the home improvement stores have the energy saving bulbs next to the regular ones so you can compare.

Comment: United States - Florida

Comment: They're regularly stocked items at Home Depot, Lowes, etc. if you have those down in FL.

Comment: I don't know that you can just grab an LED lamp based on those criteria -- the problem with LEDs is that they radiate heat out the back, not in front like a typical light; many newer LED replacement "bulbs" have an integral heat sink, but it might not get sufficient airflow if it's mounted in a can; you'll need to get a lamp that's specifically rated for use in a can so it's not a fire hazard.

Answer (score 0):

I second all the above - LED is the way to go. Home Depot (here in Central Florida) also has an LED replacement for the recessed lighting fixture that's a warm white, not a blue-white.

You can also get the recessed light floods in LED form at Target down here, although Home Depot really seems to have the best selection in a lot of areas. Their prices are also better, especially on the EcoSmart line.

The down light replacement is roughly $50, and the PAR 30 bulb itself will run roughly $40-ish depending on whether you go to HD ($40) or Target ($41).